# limit, measure, and 1 sided continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(R,B(R),m)$ be a finite measure. For function $F, G$ on $\mathbb{R}$, define
$F(x) = m((-\infty,x])$ and $G(x) = m((-\infty,x)) $

1) Prove that $F$ is right continuous while $G$ is left continuous.

2) Give an example of measure $m$ where $F$ is not left continuous and $G$ is not right continuous.

At first I was trying epsilon delta definition of one sided continuity but then I realized there is no way to set a delta since we do not really know what is measure $m$. Now I was thinking if the order of limit and measure m can be interchangeable but I am not sure... Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please visit http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for every measure $m$ on any measure space and for any sequence of measurable sets $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$, we have
$$
m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m(A_n)
$$
If the sequence satisfies $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ and $m(A_1)<\infty$ then
$$
m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m(A_n)
$$
Try to use this with some convenient sequence of sets.